# How can I use GRNN to forecast the value of a variable?

Tags: matlab, time-series, forecasting

I have some data with a fixed sample time. I divide that data into train and test set and the I train a GRNN with the training set which gives me good results. So far, so good. When I try to forecast the values for the testing set, it doesn't work (it gives me an horizontal line; always the same prediction). What can I do to make it work?

EDIT:

```
load ('dta.csv');

tam = size(dta);

data.X = (1:tam(1))'; %'
data.y = dta(:,end);

lim = round(tam(1)*0.7);

train.X = data.X(1:lim,:);
train.y = data.y(1:lim);

test.X = data.X(lim+1:end,:);
test.y = data.y(lim+1:end);


spread = 1.0;
net = newgrnn(train.X',train.y',spread);


pred = sim(net,train.X');
RMSE_TRAIN = sqrt(mean((train.y'-pred).^2))
STD_TRAIN = std(sqrt((train.y'-pred).^2))


pred = sim(net,test.X' );
RMSE_TEST = sqrt(mean((test.y'-pred).^2))
STD_TEST = std(sqrt((test.y'-pred).^2))
```

EDIT 2:

Here is the [link to dta.csv](http://www.filedropper.com/dta).

Comment: @PavelOganesyan, I just edited the post.

Comment: @Ins I think you need to post your dta.csv to debug it. It's possible you simply didn't set your spread large enough or something specific. The implementation appears correct though.

Comment: @Ins For instance, using your code with random data, I'm getting `RMSE_TRAIN = 0.2641` `STD_TRAIN = 0.0471`

Comment: @krisdestruction, here is the link for the data http://www.filedropper.com/dta